# Dart Cannot find a value in the map even through the keys are equal

Tags: dart

I have a map that has a complex object as a key

```
Map<TimeseriesNode , MyObject> myMap = {};
```

TimeseriesNode class has implemented `hashCode` and `==` operator

```
class TimeseriesNode {
  String product;
  String model;
  String element;
  String locationName;
  String locationSuffix;

  TimeseriesNode.create(this.product, this.model, this.element, this.locationName, this.locationSuffix);

  int get hashCode {
    return hashObjects([product, model, element, locationName, locationSuffix]);
  }

  bool operator ==(other) {
    if (other is! TimeseriesNode) return false;
    TimeseriesNode key = other;
    return (key.element == element 
        && key.locationName == locationName 
        && key.locationSuffix == locationSuffix 
        && key.model == model 
        && key.product == product);
  }
}
```

(method hashObjects comes from import "package:quiver/core.dart";)

One part of my application creates the keys and adds them to the map.

Another part of the application creates a new `TimeseriesNode` (which is equal to the original key) and then uses this instance to query the map.

```
MyObject obj = myMap[ node];
```

Oddly the map returns `null`. I have done some debugging and found that myMap[node] calls the following code in the dart:collection-patch_compact_hash code

```
  V operator [](Object key) {
    var v = _getValueOrData(key);
    return identical(_data, v) ? null : v;
  }
```

When I inspect `v`, I can see 'v' is the object that was originally added to the map, but the code returns null.

If I put a break point on my equals method, it is never called.

What is going on?

Comment: Have you verified that when you compare those two instances (`print(a == b)`) returns actually `true`? Do you update a field which is used to calculate the hashCode of one of the instances? Can you please add your `hashCode` and `operator ==` implementations?

Comment: What is `_data`? Please add some more code and show us your key class.

Comment: I have reworked my question to supply extra information

Comment: Can you provide a simple test case that demonstrates the issue? I've tried to reproduce it, and it works as expected. Also, don't worry about quoting code from the dart libraries.

Comment: I'd make your member variables final to start with. It is dangerous to use mutable objects as keys and can lead to strange bugs like what you are describing.

Comment: I would love to make the fields immutable, but I need to stream the class to and from JSON and that requires a public constructor with no arguments, so how can I make the fields final?

Comment: The `_data` value is just an internal value in the map implementation that is guaranteed to not be a key (because it's kept private). The code can't use `null` as marker for "not found" because `null` may be a valid key.

Answer (score 2):

The fields you use to calculate the hashcode should be immutable (final). I guess you change one of these fields after you inserted the element into the map. This results in the map not finding the instance by hashcode and therefore doesn't reach the state where it does the equals check.